# Custom javascript REST solution vs Content search webpart in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

If I have a solution to make in SP2013, I have two approaches I can do which I would like to know the advantages/disadvantages of each.

1. I could do a fully custom jquery/js/css/html solution using REST and storing cache in client side using localstorage or indexedDB. Also lazy loading so only make calls when I need it.
2. Create content search webpart with display templates.

Can anyone explain which of these is better in terms of server performance?

Assume I know REST/js/css/html fairly well.

Thanks